# How to solve non-linear stochastic differential equations

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

In general, we use Ito's formula to solve linear stochastic differential equations. Consider for instance the geometric brownian motion:

$$dX_t = \alpha X_t dt + \beta X_t dW.$$

My question is:

How can I solve this a non-linear stochastic differential equation, like:

$$dX_t = \alpha X_t dt + \beta \sqrt{X_t} dW.$$

Can I still use Ito's lemma or do I need to transform the SDE? If I have to transform the SDE, then how and what is the general rule? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe you meant $dX_t$ on your LHS.

Answer (score 1):

For most SDE, I don't think there exists "general rule" that can apply in finding their analytic solutions. For some explicitly solvable cases you may be interested in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Some_explicitly_solvable_SDEs[3]).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but non of these case you are refering to is gonna solve my problem.